# Big O notation explanation nested while loop

Tags: java, math, big-o

I was wondering what the big o notation is for the following (java)code:

```
while (n > 0) {
     while (n > 0){
        n-- ;
    }
 }
```

If I use **n = 10** it will do one iteration in the outer loop and 10 inside the inner loop. 
 So a total of **11 iterations** right? 
if I use **n = 100** it will de one iteration in the outer loop and 100 inside the inner loop. 
 So a total of **101 iterations** right? 
But this is the point where I got stuck. Because I think the notation is O(n). Simply because I think the iteration are almost equal to n.
But I don't know how to prove it?

*I am not that much in math so a clear explanation would be appriciated*

Comment: @ma3stro how does this help? He already figured out it's ``O(n)``.

Comment: Since you tagged this "java", I would like to see what the compiler creates from this code. Not sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if he would just remove the duplicate check. With respect to iterations: You have to count the number of total inner executions, which is 1 * 10 = 10 (not 1 + 10 = 11) for n = 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Informally speaking, for positive arguments, the outer loop takes exactly one iteration, as in the inner loop `n` is decreased to zero. The inner loop will take exactly `n` iterations, so the runtime complexity of the inner loop is `O(n)`. In total, although the termination condition of the outer loop syntactically depends on `n`, it is in fact independent from `n`. The overall complexity can be seen as `O(n+c)` where `c` is a constant representing the execution of the outer loop. However, `O(n+c)` equals `O(n)`.

What probably puzzles you is that in your terminology, you speak of a *number of 101 iterations* of a loop, where you in fact refer to two different loops.

Comment: This is a great explanation and also something to keep in mind when considering cases for complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; the `O` notation can be quite puzzling, especially if no rigorous definitions are provided, but instructors use a lot of handwaving.

Comment: you are right that is a mistake I  mean 101 steps in total with an input of n=100

Comment: @RickBeeloo you can't say there are 101 steps in total. If you want to count operations it's more like `(2 x condition check on outer loop) + (101 x condition check on inner loop) + (100 x decrements on n) = 203 operations`. You can't just say there are 101 steps.

Answer (score 2):

It's O(n), because the outer loop runs one single time. When the inner loop finishes, then the condition for the outer loop is also false. Therefore the outer loop is not important to the O notation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's O(n). Mathematical proofs for even simple algorithms are not easy, however.

What you could do is apply weakest precondition to formally analyze this.
See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_transformer_semantics#While_loop

Informally, it's easy to see that after the inner **while** n >= 0 must be true, regardless of what happens inside the inner loop. And if n >= 0 then the outer while will end. As this happens every single time after the inner while (regardless of it's contents), then the outer loop never executes more than once.

Weakest precondition can be used to proof this more formally, but if you apply it to bigger problems your head will definitely start to ache. It's educational though.